# Qemu VM freezes when using Tap interface on Windows

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualbox, qemu

When I try TAP Interface the qemu, the VM freezes, not sure why. But with `-netdev user` it doesn't freeze but can't connect to the VM at all.

I tested using `ESXi` and `Centos 7` both VM freezes when using `Tap` interface. `Centos 7` VM starts fine but when restarting `eth0` the VM freezes and doesn't recover. `ESXi` freezes during loading when using `Tap` interrace.

I used openVPN to create a Tap interface on windows 10, renamed the interface to Ethernet7 and used the following command when running `Qemu` VM.

```
-netdev tap,ifname=Ethernet7,script=no,downscript=no,id=hostnet0 -device e1000,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=DE:AD:BE:EF:16:B6
```

I downloaded the latest Windows version of Qemu from qemu.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: TAP interface wasn't working due to Windows 10 Tap interface was using a old 2014 driver. I created a new interface (using `hdwwiz.exe`) and I had the option to select 2019 driver instead of old driver. TAP interface works fine and doesn't freeze the VM.

`User mode` networking also works fine if you don't need TAP interface.

`qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -hda centos.img -m 2048 -smp cpus=2,cores=2 -netdev user,id=n1,hostfwd=tcp::2222-:22 -device e1000,netdev=n1`

In the `Centos` I had to run the command `dhclient eth0` as it doesn't get dhcp IP assigned automatically. After running the command, the VM gets the IP address of `10.0.2.15` and then I can SSH to it using `ssh -p 2222 root@localhost`.

For ESXi, I had to enable SSHD in the ESXi settings and use localhost to connect. ICMP doesn't work for both in `User mode` networking.

`qemu-system-x86_64 -boot d -hda esxi.img -m 4096 -cpu Westmere -machine q35 -smp cpus=2,cores=2 -accel tcg -netdev user,id=n1,hostfwd=tcp::2223-:22,hostfwd=tcp::9443-:443,hostfwd=tcp::8085-:80 -device e1000,netdev=n1`